# How can I import the latest version of pandas in my Jupyter Sagemaker notebook instance?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

Whenever I run this code in a cell:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
```

I get the following:

```
'0.24.2'
```

I would like to be able to import the latest version of pandas right off the bat.  When I look at the Conda Packages under *Kernel* -> *Conda Packages*, I can see that pandas 1.0.1 is installed.  I would like to avoid having to do `!pip install --upgrade pandas` every time I run this notebook.  Is there a way to do that?  I'm confused by the fact that conda seems to have pandas 1.0.1 installed but it only imports version 0.24.2.

I saw that you can specify the version of pandas via lifecycle configurations, but I was hoping there was a more permanent solution that automatically does it instead of me having to specify it.

Comment: You might be running a notebook instance for a long time. In my notebook the default version is 1.0.1

Comment: I stop my notebook instance every day, so it's effectively restarted every night.

Answer (score 2):

You can run the needed pip upgrade as part of the [lifecycle configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebook-lifecycle-config.html) whenever the notebook is started. So it will be ready once you open the notebook.

Comment: Do AWS Sagemaker Jupyter instances not import the latest version of a library by default?  In other words, why would pandas 0.24.2 be imported when version 1.0.1 is installed as part of the Conda packages?

Answer (score 0):

An onstart Lifecycle configuration is what you need.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# OVERVIEW
# This script installs a single conda package in a single SageMaker conda environments.

sudo -u ec2-user -i <<'EOF'
# PARAMETERS
ENVIRONMENT=my_environment
nohup conda update pandas --yes --name "$ENVIRONMENT"
EOF
```